# Angular2 create dynamic components in different places by calling component methods

Tags: angular, dynamic, components

I have different components (Parent/child and siblings). What i want is **The share method which creates dynamic components in different places**. In other words I want to access other component methods to call them and create dynamic component.

I know about shared service but it isn't helpful for creating component because of this error : `Cannot read property 'resolveComponentFactory' of undefined`

This is what I achieve. And this works fine.

**first.component.ts**

```
import { secondComponent } from './secondComponent';
import { testComponent } from './testComponent';

@component({
  template: `<div #target></div>`
})

@ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target: ViewContainerRef;

compInstance:any;
ngOnInit(){
  let factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(secondComponent);
  this.compInstance = this.target.createComponent(factory);

  //this is how I pass loadComponent method to component
  this.compInstance.instance.firstComponentMethod = this;
}

//this is shared method
loadComponent(){
  this.target.clear();
  let factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(testComponent);
  this.target.createComponent(factory);
}
```

**second.component.ts**

```
import { firstComponent } from './firstComponent';

@Input() firstComponentMethod:firstComponent;

ngOnInit(){

  //this method loads 'testComponent' component 
  this.firstComponentMethod.loadComponent();
}
```

**But** as you can see I only pass current component methods to component instance with help of `this` keyword here -> `this.compInstance.instance.firstComponentMethod = this;` I also want to pass other component methods but don't know how.And also can't find another way to solve my problem. **so any help will be appreciated**

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html this can help

Comment: "different places" can only be where you have a `ViewContainerRef` reference available. I'd suggest you inject the service to the component where you want the dynamic component be created and there you subscribe to an observable of the service and then add the component when the observable emits a value.

Comment: [might be of interest](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)

Comment: Thank you. Sounds good can you provide some code?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  I almost implemented observable, But I have one question about performance.. as I understand I have never evoke `observer.complete()` because of listening it and there are so many components which i want to subscribe and is it normal to have 15 - 20 uncompleted Observable ?

Comment: If the subscribers don't expect the observable to complete, it's fine. Ensure you unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` in the components to not keep subscriptions of destroyed components.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you so mush ))